# How to integrate Vue/NuxtJs with Ezoic?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, virtual-dom

Ezoic provides web publishers with automated website intelligence for their ads, content, layouts, and more.

Ezoic can by only integrated by Cloudflare or name servers - https://support.ezoic.com/support/solutions/articles/48000453862-how-can-i-integrate-my-site-with-ezoic-

The ezoic server is replacing ad-placeholders with ad scripts.

Example:

```
<span id="ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-100"></span> ---> ad script
```

The question is how do I connect it with NuxtJS and Vue. After hydration, the ad script is removed and replaced with the placeholder. Can I tell Vue - DON'T RE-RENDER THAT FRAGMENT OF CODE?

**Component Code:**

```
<template>
    <div class="google-ads" :class="`google-ads--${type}`">
        <template v-if="type === 'top'">
            <!-- Ezoic - standard - top_of_page -->
            <div id="ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-102"></div>
            <!-- End Ezoic - standard - top_of_page -->
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```